# How do I refresh the page after a DropdownList changes so that JavaScript will be executed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know the title is confusing, so I'll evplaiin what i'm trying to do.
I am using the [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) plugin to create a syntax-highlighted text area in MVC 5. I have a dropdownlist with a range of available languages that can be highlighted. I want to be able to swith the textarea language when the DDL changes. Right now, it is always stuck at the first language. Heres What I have So Far:
Model--->

```
 public class CodeSnip
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public StringBuilder Code { get; set; }
        public LangType Language { get; set; }
   }

    public enum LangType
    {
        CSharp,                
        css,
        HTML,
        JavaScript,
        Perl,
        PHP,
        Python,
        Ruby,
        SQL,
        VB,
        XML,
        Other
    }
```

The controller simply calls the appropriate view, no logic in there yet.
HTML/RAZOR--->

```
@using AFGCodeBox.Models
@model AFGCodeBox.Models.CodeSnip

<script src="/Scripts/CodeMirror/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/CodeMirror/clike.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/css.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/perl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/php.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/python.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/ruby.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/sql.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/vb.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CodeMirror/xml.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/eclipse.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>AFG Codebox</h1>
    <p class="lead">Create your style here</p>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", id = "title", placeholder = "Codesnip Title", style = "width: 200px", @maxlength = "50" })
    @Html.DropDownList("Language",
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(LangType))),
    "Select Language", new {id="codeDDl"})
    <p></p>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", id = "description", placeholder = "Codesnip Description",style = "Width: 800px" })
    <p></p>
    <div id="CodeBlock">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Code, new { id = "code" })
    </div>




}
    <script>

        switch(document.getElementById("codeDDl").selectedIndex) {

        case 1:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-csharp"
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-css"
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-html"
            });
            break;
        case 4:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-javascript"
            });
            break;
        }

    </script>
```

You can see the DDL, codeDDL, which I want to fire the javascript case statement; but like I said it only calls index 0.
Is there a way to change the code boxes syntax by changing the selected index of the DDL?

Comment: Bind a Javascript onchange event to the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like this :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Language",
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(LangType))),
    "Select Language", 
    new {id="codeDDl", @onchange="changeEditor()"})

function changeEditor(){
 switch(document.getElementById("codeDDl").selectedIndex) {

        case 1:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-csharp"
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-css"
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-html"
            });
            break;
        case 4:
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "text/x-javascript"
            });
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: This works, but for some reason appends a whole new editor control when the selection changes

Comment: Maybe keep the editor instance and only change is mode ? I didn't pay attention to the plugin api

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to refresh the page, just bind an event handler to your drop down element and listen for event 'change' (which is fired when user select a value from drop down list), in the callback function add your code.

Below an example just to show the principal:

```js
document.getElementById("codeDDl").addEventListener('change',function(e){
console.log('your code execute here!');

});
```

```html
<select id="codeDDl">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This does the same thing, appends a textbox instead of keeping the same one. I probably wasn't clear in my question.